# I have an Objective-C statement, who can help me translate into Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
[self.resultController setCellForRowAtIndexPathCompletion:^UITableViewCell *(UITableView *tableView, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

}];
```

This function is defined as follows:

```
@property (copy) UITableViewCell * (^cellForRowAtIndexPathCompletion)(UITableView *tableView, NSIndexPath *indexPath);
```

Comment: That's called a "Block" in Objective-C and a "Closure" in Swift in case you were looking for "key word" to improve your search.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **closure** that can be defined like this:

```
var cellForRowAtIndexPathCompletion: ((_ tableView: UITableView, _ indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell)!
```

Comment: I use it like this:self.resultController.cellForRowAtIndexPathCompletion ((tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell)!{
}  but have a error : Cannot convert value of type '((UITableView, IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell).Type' to expected argument type '(UITableView?, IndexPath?)' (aka '(Optional<UITableView>, Optional<IndexPath>)')

Comment: You should not use a forced unwrapp (!) on a property unless you are 100% sure it will always be set, or even better, unless it is a IBOutlet

Comment: How should I code?